# What does this printf mean?

Tags: c, printf

```
printf("%c","abcdefgh"[4]);
```

The output of the following program is `e`. But I don't know how it is? I searched a lot in google and here but didn't find the correct explanation for this code. The explanation I am getting for this code:

> "This is for getting one `char` only. i.e, the 4th `char` starts from `0`. So the answer is `'e'`".

Comment: Exactly. `%c` prints one character, and `[4]` indexes 4 characters into the string.

Comment: "What does [this code] mean?" pretty much always strikes me as an excessively-local question, by the way; it's not something posed in a way to be easy for others to find and learn from... especially here, where're you're conflating two questions (what does indexing into a string do, and what does printf `%c` mean)

Comment: "abcdefgh" is an array and "e" is its the 4th element (counting from 0, of course). You are printing it as a char.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy To help the future visitors please feel free to edit these question.

Comment: This must be an exercise/interview/trick question.  I've never seen a use for indexing into a string literal array like this in practice.  I guess it would be fair to say this is a question for an "enthusiast". :-)

Comment: @JoshPetitt : I am reading a C puzzle book, there I saw this question.

Comment: http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/83341.html

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi: You could also write: `printf("%c", 4["abcdefgh"]);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals are arrays, and as such can be indexed into: `"abcdefgh"[0]` is `'a'`, for example.

Comment: Is string literal itself the identifier for the array? Strange. Never got to know such thing allowed in the language.

Comment: @Mahesh: Technically no, it just magically *is* the value, but colloquially you could say that.

Answer (score 1):

you could write it like this:

```
char *tmp="abcdefgh";
printf("%c",tmp[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%c","abcdefgh"[4]);
```

The format string is `"%c"`, which means that `printf` shall print one character. The character it shall print is

```
"abcdefgh"[4]
```

i.e. the character at index `4` of the `char[9]` `"abcdefgh"`, which is the character `'e'`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a string is represented as array so this statement

```
printf("%c","abcdefgh"[4]);
```

is equivalent to

```
char a[] = "abcdefgh";
printf("%c",a[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%c` prints one character. So to explain why you get "e" as the output `a` has index 0, `b` has index 1, `c` has index 2, `d` has index 3, and finally `e` has index 4. Which is what you selected to print (`[4]`). Which is why "e" is the output.